# Convert string with multiple quotes to normal String in python

Tags: python, string

Through reading a file I get strings in the following format `'"content"'`. How can I convert this string to a normal string with one quote?

Comment: Can you please show a larger example of the text containing this quoted word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = '"content"'
print('len_a = ',len(a))
b = a.strip('""')
print('len_b = ',len(b))
```

Output:

```
len_a =  9
len_b =  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the " quote with an empty string

```
a = '"content"'.replace('"', '') 
  
print(a)
>>> 'content'
```

Comment: You might wanna change the word nothing to empty string

Comment: why are u converting a string again to string?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is completely dependent on the strings you're working with. For example, if the string contained a quote in the middle, the answers about replacing all quotes won't work for you.
If the additional quotes are always the first and last character, and the strings are always non-empty, this can be used:

```
string = string[1:-1]
```

But again, we'll need more info on what you're working with, to provide an appropriate answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
string = '"content"'
string = string.replace('\"', '\'')
```

I hope I understood you correctly